# How can I display recurring Events in CQWP with item type "event"?

Tags: calendar, content-query-web-part, recurring-events

I have a CQWP to display a list of upcoming events for the next 2 weeks of every calendar on a site collection. To do so, I use a filter Attribute only available when choosing "event" to be the item type of the CQWP.

Unfortunatly, I don't see any recurring events in the result apart from the very first appearance of the events.

I did find a [TechNet thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/89cecbc1-c056-4a29-89d2-ab4e6e864a7f/recurring-events-in-content-query-web-part), suggesting to use "item" as the item type of the CQWP - but this doesn't work for me because with this item type I lose the ability to filter by event's start date.

Is there any other possibilty to show recurring events in a CQWP when using "event" as item type?

**UPDATE 1**

[Moudhafer's answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/162572/48637) did help me to apply the custom query I need to the CQWP when using the item type "item". But still, there aren't any recurring events appearing for more than the very first time in the result. I did make sure to use item type "item" and that the feature "team collaboration lists" is enabled as described in the TechNet thread I mentioned above.

I guess, there must be more to it than that ... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the CQWP is that you can not put what you want on the query.
Luckily you can use the property QueryOverride.

1. Download the WP
2. Edit the XML file
3. Change the QueryOverride proeprty and use something like that :
4. Upload the WP to the Web Parts catalog.
5. Insert the new WP on your page.

Comment: I guess you put some CAML below point nr. 3 - but I can't see anything there ... Please have a look! Right now I'm trying to figure out how to write CAML that works and if I could see your suggestion to point nr. 3 I'd probably succeed much faster!

Comment: Hi, sorry i did not pay attention, have a look on this page to find the good CAML query : [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/eb58847d-914f-4ce1-a8d8-ef874d14c50c/caml-query-getting-recurring-events-in-sharepoint-calendar)

Comment: Okay, your answer did help me to get the custom query i need to be applied on the CQWP when using the item type "item". So, I really would like to mark it as correct answer. Sadly, I can't because it didn't solve my problem ... Still, there aren't any recurring events appearing more often than the very first time. Though I did make sure to use item type "item" and that the feature "team collaboration lists" is enabled as described in the thread i found.

Comment: Now i see.You want to see as much as item as you have recurrence. For instance if you have a recurrent event "Every day" you want to see 1 4 entries on the CQWP, true? well this is not possible.Why?
The CQWP will generate a SPSiteDataQuery to get all the SPListItems matching the query. If you create a recurrent event the list will get only 1 item.
If you need to perform so, you have to make a custom development.
The solution i proposed will just show an event only one time, as long as he has future recurrency...